# Elm_entry: centering text?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I know I can use formats in text to center it within an `elm_entry`.

Also when I'm setting the guide text, it can be aligned center by some format strings:

```
<text_class=tizen align=center>input your text</>
```

However, when user needs to fill the entry, text is not aligned center:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Even if I apply the markup text to the entry:

**When entry's content is erased, markup text is lost:**

```
<text_class=tizen align=center>Some nice centered text</>
//keep clearing:
<text_class=tizen align=center>Some nice centered tex</>
<text_class=tizen align=center>Some nice centered te</>
<text_class=tizen align=center>Some nice centered t</>
.
.
.
<text_class=tizen align=center>S</>
#EMPTY!!! Next time pressing a key:
S
So
Some
```

Can I somehow move the cursor and also the first letter into the center?

Answer (score 0):

Entry content and cursor have theme dependency.
So it can not be controlled by a third-party through the api.

I think it is possible to customize the theme of the entry, but it is complicated.
Perhaps the text area should be increases every time text is input from the center.

Please refer to the public theme repo.
https://review.tizen.org/gerrit/#/admin/projects/profile/wearable/platform/core/uifw/efl-theme-tizen-wearable

And if the entry is located in the center of the vertical, if the s/w keyboard appears, it may cause an incorrect position as shown in the 2nd picture.
In this case, you need to adjust the size of the entry when the keyboard is shown. But I think this is inconvenient.

In general, reference places the entry at the top of view.

- public demo :
  https://review.tizen.org/gerrit/#/admin/projects/profile/wearable/platform/core/uifw/elm-demo-tizen-wearable

Comment: Both links are inaccessible.